# How Can I Make A GUI Pop-Up When A Player First Plays On ROBLOX?

Tags: user-interface, scripting, roblox

I Want To Make A Tutorial On How To Play My Game, So I Need A GUI To Pop-Up On The First Time A Player Joins The Game.

Can Anyone Help?

Answer (score 0):

Place the ScreenGui you want to clone in Lighting and name it "Tutorial". Then add this code in a LocalScript in the Player's StarterGui:

```
game.Lighting.Tutorial:clone().Parent = script.Parent
script:Destroy()
```